# iOS : In Swift 3, how to remove the n last rows from a section in a two-dimentional array?

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, swift3

I created a two-dimensional array, and I would like to remove the n last rows from a section.

Example:

```
var timeTable : [[Int]] = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: 50), count: models.count)

for i in (0..<models.count)
    {
    timeTable[i] = timeTable[i].dropLast(50 - models[i].slots.count) //=> problem: Cannot assign value of type 'ArraySlice<Int>' to type '[Int]'
    for j in (0..<models[i].slots.count)
        {
        print("model:",i, ", slots:", j)

        let minutes =  models[i].slots[j].endDate.minutes(from: models[i].slots[j].startDate)
        print(minutes)

        timeTable[i][j] = minutes
        }
    }
```

Here is an example of my models :
[image]

The values for models[i].slots.count are different, rarely the same.

I want to do that because I have to allocate the place for the rows of the array, I don't know how to allocate it... So I allocate 50 first, and during the loop, I remove the last rows that aren't useful... (If if is possible to allocate first, I should prefer...)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And `models[i].slots.count` is different for each models row? Give us an example of your `models` array if possible

Comment: @ Ladislav, the models[i].slots.count are different for each model, exactly. I put an example of the models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do this:

```
var timeTable : [[Int]] = []
for model in models {
    let modelArray = Array(repeating: 0, count:model.slots.count)
    timeTable.append(modelArray)
}
```

Comment: I take this :D Thank you very much. Simple and direct.

Comment: Yeah no need to create an array to big just to make it smaller since you already know at that point how big subarrays should be ;)